# Make alias from existing alias

Tags: shell-script, zsh, alias

I have 2 separate files, which are both sourced from my `.zshrc`, one of them (the first one) is defining this alias:

```bsh
alias wget='wget --hsts-file="$XDG_CACHE_HOME/wget-hsts"'
```

problem is that the other one, sourced after this one is also defining `wget` alias:

```bsh
alias wget='wget -c'
```

I need to somehow ensure, that the second alias defines itself using the previous alias.
I was thinking of using something like `$(wget)`, but that just gets me into a recursive loop.
Is there some good way to reference an already existing alias with the same name while defining a new one?

I was maybe thinking of somehow getting the content of the first alias and only concatenating that with my new flag so that it will build on the previous alias, I'd probably also have to do some handling to fall back to the real command if the command wasn't already aliased before.

*Note: I know that I could just change the name of one of those aliases and reference it in the next one, but that's not what I'm asking for. Nor do I want to just simply define them as 1 alias manually. I want a way to actually automatically use the old alias definition when defining a new one, so that they get chained together .*

Any idea how could I implement something like this? Or perhaps a better method to do something like this?

Comment: you tagged with Bash but mention zsh, what do shell do you actually use?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I use zsh, but it shouldn't matter, I think the aliases behave in the same way in both, I might be wrong but I'm not aware of any difference

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I've changed the tags, and what I meant was that I didn't want the first alias to just be directly combined with the second manually, by specifying both tags in a single alias, but rather a method of doing this automatically

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes, I've adjusted the question too, it should be clearer that they should be automatically merged into a single alias.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You are defining an alias in one way and then redefining it afterwards. Rather than an alias, you're better off using a function and calling it something different.

Comment: @NasirRiley I know it won't work as is, that's why I'm asking about it. But I'm trying to somehow define it as an alias that can build on top of the previous alias, I'm fine with a function that would be able to generate the content of that alias, so that it can be used on multiple aliases, perhaps just a way to get the content of the previous alias and define the new one with using that, for example something like `alias wget=fromalias wget additional flags`, so I'm asking about how should such function work or perhaps some different better way to approach this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`aliases` hash table](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-aliases) for this:

```bsh
% zmodload -F zsh/parameter p:aliases
% alias wget='wget --hsts-file="$XDG_CACHE_HOME/wget-hsts"'
% alias wget="$aliases[wget] -c"
% alias
wget='wget --hsts-file="$XDG_CACHE_HOME/wget-hsts" -c'
```

> I'd probably also have to do some handling to fall back to the real command if the command wasn't already aliased before

That can be achieved by using `${aliases[wget]:-wget}`. Then, if `$aliases[wget]` is empty, the literal value `wget` will be used instead.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with some ugly parsing of the `alias` output:

```
$ alias foo='foo --first'
$ alias foo=$(alias foo | cut --delimiter== --fields=2 | head --bytes=-2 | tail --bytes=+2)' --second'
$ alias foo
alias foo='foo --first --second'
```

Of course, if `alias` ever prints the alias in any other format (multiple lines or different quotes) all bets are off. It also does not handle the case where the alias is not already set:

```
$ unalias foo
$ alias foo=$(alias foo | cut --delimiter== --fields=2 | head --bytes=-2 | tail --bytes=+2)' --second'
bash: alias: foo: not found
$ alias foo
alias foo=' --second'
```

Comment: OP uses Zsh, not Bash.

Comment: @MarlonRichert Not my fault IMO, since OP tagged it Bash originally. I'll leave this here for reference for any Bash users.